# Find the The number of ways of distributing 12 identical oranges among 4 children so that every child gets atleast 1 and no child more than 4

Tags: combinatorics

The number of ways of distributing 12 identical oranges among 4 children so that every child gets atleast 1 and no child more than 4 is

Comment: Its among four children

Answer (score 2):

Give each child one orange, then distribute the remaining eight so that no child receives more than three additional apples.

Count and add the permutations of each of: $(3,3,2,0), (3,3,1,1), (3,2,2,1), (2,2,2,2)$.

---

Or simply count and add the permutations of each of: $(4,4,3,1), (4,4,2,2), (4,3,3,2), (3,3,3,3)$.

Comment: The oranges have not been distributed yet... :)

Answer (score 2):

There can be four possible cases.

> 1. {4,4,3,1} , no. of combinations $= \frac{4!}{2!}=12$
> 2. {4,4,2,2} , no. of combinations $= \frac{4!}{2!2!}=6$
> 3. {4,3,3,2} , no. of combinations $= \frac{4!}{2!}=12$
> 4. {3,3,3,3} , no. of combinations $= \frac{4!}{4!}=1$.

Adding them, $12+6+12+1=31$